# Is/was there an "inside joke" style badge?

Tags: discussion

I am curious as to whether there is/are troll badges on Stack Exchange which are meant as a joke. Not as a reward for good behavior or achievement  ... like some of the troll trophies in the [PlayStation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation)/[Xbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox) communities..

Comment: Well, at one time there were joke-ish _reputation points_ to be gained on an April 1. Those were gone the next day.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> troll badges in stack which are meant as a joke

No. That would cheapen the whole idea of badges and work against them as motivators.

Comment: it's cool to see as many upticks on this answer as the downticks on the  question... which one do you think will win lol

Comment: @kushan now its an absolute tie ( -20 ,20)

Answer (score 5):

As was pointed out in other answers - that would defeat the purpose of badges. Badges are meant to encourage good behavior.

However, we do have [Winterbash hats](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/). During the winter holiday, users can earn hats - temporary adornments for their avatars. Since these awards are temporary, these *can* afford to have some jokes.

For example, during Winterbash 2014 we had "Hairboat", followed in 2015 by "Hairboat's Revenge". The first was received by commenting on any post by Abby Hairboat, an SE employee. The second was obtained by commenting on any post by Jon Ericson - the SE employee who had come up with the "Hairboat" hat. So, "Hairboat's Revenge" was an inside joke for Winterbash veterans.

Comment: Yeah, and the fall out from both those hats wasn't pleasant for the moderators to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "inside joke" badges.  You can see all of the badges that were available on [Help Center -> Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).  Badges which can no longer be awarded are marked as "retired."

Comment: thats why i have kept the "was" in the question... anyway nice to know...

Comment: @Kushan I understand.  That's why I wrote that all badges are visible, even the ones that can no longer be awarded.